Itext7 Digital Signature not visible
I'm using itext7 to digitally sign a pdf using a custom apperance. I opened the document using append mode and for rotated pages the signature is not displayed correctly. I tried to set the setIgnorePageRotationForContent but it looks like is not applied for layer2 content of signature appearance.
Here is a sample:
ItextTextPdf.PdfReader reader = new ItextTextPdf.PdfReader(stream);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
    StampingProperties stamping = new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode();
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, writer, stamping);
    PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
    signatureAppearance.SetReason(Reason);
    signatureAppearance.SetLocation(Reason);
    Rectangle signRectangle = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(llx, lly, width, height);
    var page = signer.GetDocument().GetPage(SignatureSettings.Page);
    page.SetIgnorePageRotationForContent(true);
    signatureAppearance.SetPageRect(signRectangle).SetPageNumber(SignatureSettings.Page);
    bouncyCastleCrypto.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new    bouncyCastleCrypto.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
    bouncyCastleCrypto.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] pk = new bouncyCastleCrypto.Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
    signer.SignDetached(new AlliumDMSSigner.X509Certificate2Signature(cert, HashAlgorithmName), pk, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);


Please share an example file before and after signing for analysis.

Hello! It looks like the solution that you provide here is working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273587/visible-signature-created-using-itext-7-not-shown-in-chrome

Ok. Shall we close this question of yours as a duplicate of that other question?

I just have one more think here. It looks like setIgnorePageRotationForContent doesn't work for annotations, only for content. Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue with rotated files? @mkl

Can you create a new question about that, showing your code and sketching what you expect and what you get instead? (As this question has no real answers yet, you could alternatively edit it that way.)

Sure, I’ve just updated the content! @mkl
